# Regular expression for year sequence

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So I'm trying to match something like

```
2011,2012,2013
```

or

```
2011,
```

or

```
2011
```

but NOT:

`2011,201` or `2011,201,2012`

I tried with `([0-9]{4},?([0-9]{4},?)*)` but if the first year is matched, it does not consider the rest .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close.

```
 ^[0-9]{4}(?:,[0-9]{4})*,?$
```

That will match any string consisting of a repeating sequence of 4-digit numbers and commas.

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, respectively. Thus, it will only match if the string consists of *only* those elements.

The `(?:)` is a non-capture group. It allows you to create repeating groups without storing all of them into variables.

**EDIT:** Forgot about the optional comma at the end. Added a `,?` to take care of it.

**EDIT 2:** At FailedDev's advice, here was my original idea. It also works, but I think it is harder to understand. It is more clever, but that's not always a good thing.

```
^(:?[0-9]{4}(?:,|$))+$
```

Comment: The `2011,` case is not covered (yes... I agree it's ugly, but it's there). Also there is an unbalanced parenthesis at the end.

Comment: You mean my very first one? It was so ugly!

Comment: @6502 I fixed that 47 seconds before you commented ;)

Comment: nice, thank you for your help. Much appreciated. This will do just fine

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick...

```
 /^[0-9]{4}(,[0-9]{4})*,?$/
```

i.e. 4 digits followed by zero or more of (a comma followed by 4 digits) and optionally a last (bad looking) comma before the end.

The first `^` and last `$` chars ensure that nothing else can be present in the string.

Comment: @FailedDev: whoops... you're right (even if accepting `2011,` to me looks strange... why not `,2011` or `,,,2011,,` then ?)

Comment: Well I don't know. Ask the OP :)

Comment: the previous regex you posted kind of worked. I was gonna trim the trailing comma's if it were the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (subject.match(/^\d{4}(?:,?|(?:,\d{4}))+$/)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

This should work.

**Explanation :**

```
"^" +              // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"\\d" +             // Match a single digit 0..9
   "{4}" +            // Exactly 4 times
"(?:" +            // Match the regular expression below
   "|" +              // Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      "," +              // Match the character “,” literally
         "?" +              // Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   "|" +              // Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      "(?:" +            // Match the regular expression below
         "," +              // Match the character “,” literally
         "\\d" +             // Match a single digit 0..9
            "{4}" +            // Exactly 4 times
      ")" +
")+" +             // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"$"                // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:\d{4},?)*$/
```

Checks for four digits, each possibly followed by a comma, 0 to many times

Comment: change the `*` to a `+` if you want to make sure there is at least one year in the string.

Comment: This will match 3049858499028439753955028.

Comment: no it won't. Tested in Node. `/^(?:\d{4},?)*$/.test('3049858499028439753955028'); // false`

Comment: the `{4}` after the `\d` will not allow 5+ digits. It wants exactly four.

Comment: My bad, I didn't actually count the numbers, as my point was that the comma being optional is wrong. Any string of a multiple of 4 numbers will match. Try it with 304985849902843975395502.

Comment: good call. `/^(?:\d{4}(?!\d),?)*$/` instead would work. My bad.